# How can I count the widgets stored in a Gtk::Grid?

Tags: gtkmm

I am looking for several gtkmm methods/data types that are equivalent to some QT expressions:

1. given a widget container in QT (e.g. `QBoxLayout`), a simple method called `count()` returns the amout of widgets stored in the given container. The best way to exchange QBoxLayout or any QT widget container is `Gtk::Grid`. But there is no simple way to get the amount of widgets inside of it. Same with `Gtk::Box`.

   I need that method to iterate the childs stored in the grid:

   ```cpp
   for(auto& it : layouts) { //layouts is a vector of Gtk::Grids         
       for(int i = 0; i < it->size(); ++i) {                                                                
           if(it->get_child_at(0, i)) {  
               it->get_child_at(0, i)->set_visible((std::string(it->get_name())== StringID));                       
           }
   ```
2. QT uses `QWidget` as an object unbounded to any widget type (such as a button or a checkbox..). That is not possible in gtkmm, because Widgets can only be initinalized with a reference to a widget type. Now I'm looking to replace a QT code with gtkmm, that has a vector of widgets. I used  Gtk::Box to replace the QWidgets. Is that a reasonable replacement? I'm getting trouble replacing their scale, which was originally dealt with using `QSize`, expecting two numbers "hight" and "lenght". Now there is a `Gtk::Scale` class, but it works in a different way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Gtkmm containers (like `Gtk::Grid`) inherit from the `Gtk::Container`, which makes the following methods available:

```cpp
std::vector<Widget*> get_children()               // Non const: to modify the widgets
std::vector<const Widget*> get_children () const  // const: for read operations
```

These methods return exactly what you want: a vector of widgets. You can use [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) on the returned `std::vector` to count the number of wigets in the container.

Also, in my opinion, `Gtk::Box` is very rarely useful since it is very limited. `Gtk::Grid` is almost always a better choice.

Finally, in Qt, all graphical elements inherit from `QWidget`. In Gtkmm, all widgets inherit from `Gtk::Widget`, meaning that you can write something like:

```cpp
Gtk::Widget* pButton = new Gtk::Button("My button");
```

and then use `pButton`, which is "unbounded to any widget type". See [the reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html) for more information on `Gtk::Widget`.

---

**Update for Gtkmm4**

It seems `Gtk::Container` was removed in Gtkmm4 as documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/changes-gtkmm4.html.en). There seems to be nothing to replace it. Unfortunately, it looks like in this version, child widgets tracking will have to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution. Unfortunetely, in my version of gtkmm, there is no such class as `Gtk::Container`, thus creating the error of unknown member `get_children()`. I checked for `Gtk::Grid` reference and it confirmed that Gtk::Container is no longer a thing.. [Gtk::Grid reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Grid.html)

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: 3.24.3-3. Upgrading is not possible atm

Comment: You are right in saying that `Gtk::Container` is no longer a thing, but this is true for Gtkmm4 (See changes list [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/changes-gtkmm4.html.en). In Gtkmm 3.24, `Gtk::Container` still is defined, as show by the [Gtkmm 3.24 reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1Container.html#details).

Comment: yeah I checked for it as well, thats really strange. I will go over my compiler settings. Again, thanks alot for your solution!

Comment: By the way, look at [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/) to make sure you select the right reference for your Gtkmm version. The link you provided above for `Gtk::Grid` is the "stable" version, which is 4.0.1. Unfortunately the Gtkmm API has changed massively from the version 3 to the version 4 :-(